# Is creating many object reduce performance?

Tags: java, object

in my code i have around 150 users details to save or trivers many time.

Which one is better approach:

save user details in list or in objects;

```
Map<String, List<String>> users= new Map<String, List<String>>();
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
data.add(Name);
data.add(address);
data.add(phone);
users.put(userID,data);
```

Or

```
Map<String, UserData> users= new Map<String, UserData>();

public class UserData {
    Public String name;
    Public String address;
    Public String phone;
    UserData(String name,String address,String phone){
        this.name=name;
        this.address=address;
        this.phone=phone;
     }
 }  

UserData userData=new UserData("Name","ADD","123") ;
users.put(userID,userData);
```

Please suggest me if any other better approach i can use in my code.
and sorry for bad English.

Comment: The first one depends on the order of adding the datas into the list. The second one is much cleaner.

Comment: You only create one more object in the second example - it won't make much difference, especially for such a small number (150).

Comment: [Item 55: Optimize judiciously](http://homepages.dcc.ufmg.br/~rodolfo/dcc030-2-11/Effective%20Java%20Item%2055.htm)

Comment: Either way the data is going to get stored in memory irrespective of the approaches.Always profile and check for performance issues.

Comment: Object approach is better in all aspect: memory/readability/maintainability.

Comment: why don't you add userId as member in UserData, and make array of UserData? UserData users = new UserData[10];

Comment: Using a `new ArrayList<String>()` instead of a `new UserData` uses actually more objects. There is the `ArrayList` instance itself and there is an internal array created internally by the list. #2 uses exactly 1 object. So #2 is both cleaner and creating less objects.

Answer (score 5):

Java is designed around objects and the JVM handles them very well.

Design your system how it should be designed, using the tried and tested best practise of OO design.  If there are performance issues (most likely there won't be), then address that problem when you get to it.

Comment: Exactly. And address it with *real*, measured data. If you can't measure it, you can't improve it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many, many details to set to an object the second approach is the correct one. As this is the only way to tell what data actually represents.

The first one is a simple list of items where you rely on the fact that some data is on some location. But what if a part of the data is missing ... what then ... will you insert null's instead? Not a good way to store meaningful data.

Creating classes with many properties can lead to an inconsistent state while they are being initialized. As you rely on the fact that each property is set after creation and that some properties are not null when you are using this class.

Therefore I would suggest to use the [builder pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html) in such case.